# How to get multiple records join into one table or use contain with conditions?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, join

I'm using cakePHP 2.6.4.
I have two tables `AgentChat` and `AgentChatMember`.
`AgentChat` hasMany `AgentChatMember`,
`AgentChatMember` belongsTo `AgentChat`.

`AgentChat` have: `id, team_id, agent_chat_member_count` fields.
`AgentChatMember` have: `id, agent_chat_id, user_id` fields.

I want to find `AgentChat` by `chat_team_id` and `agent_chat_member_count`,
and `AgentChatMember` as contain with `user_id` conditions.

```
    $options['contain'] = array('AgentChatMember');
    $options['conditions']['AgentChat.agent_chat_member_count'] = count($user_ids);
    $options['conditions']['AgentChat.chat_team_id'] = $chat_team_id;

    $res = $this->AgentChat->find('first', $options);
```

and `$res` is:

```
     'AgentChat' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'agent_message_count' => '0',
        'agent_chat_member_count' => '2',
        'chat_team_id' => '14',
        'created' => '2015-05-06 09:52:31',
        'updated' => '2015-05-06 09:52:31'
    ),
    'AgentChatMember' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'agent_chat_id' => '1',
            'user_id' => '26',
            'created' => '2015-05-06 09:52:31'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'agent_chat_id' => '1',
            'user_id' => '21',
            'created' => '2015-05-06 09:52:31'
        )
    )
```

By this i get what i want except fact i cant set `user_id` condition to `AgentChatMember` like this: `$options['conditions']['AgentChatMember.user_id'] = $user_ids;`

When i'm using joins instead of contain i can set user_id conditions, but i get result like this:

```
(int) 0 => array(
        'AgentChat' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'agent_message_count' => '0',
            'agent_chat_member_count' => '2',
            'chat_team_id' => '14',
            'created' => '2015-05-06 09:52:31',
            'updated' => '2015-05-06 09:52:31'
        ),
        'AgentChatMember' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'agent_chat_id' => '1',
            'user_id' => '21',
            'created' => '2015-05-06 09:52:31'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'AgentChat' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'agent_message_count' => '0',
            'agent_chat_member_count' => '2',
            'chat_team_id' => '14',
            'created' => '2015-05-06 09:52:31',
            'updated' => '2015-05-06 09:52:31'
        ),
        'AgentChatMember' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'agent_chat_id' => '1',
            'user_id' => '26',
            'created' => '2015-05-06 09:52:31'
        )
    ),
    ...
```

Its possible to get multiple records join into one table or contain with conditions on it?
How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass [conditions to the contain](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html):-

```
$res = $this->AgentChat->find(
    'first',
    array(
        'contain' => array(
            'AgentChatMember' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'AgentChatMember.user_id' => $userIds
                )
            )
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'AgentChat.agent_chat_member_count' => count($userIds),
            'AgentChat.chat_team_id' => $chatTeamId
        )
    )
);
```

Just as an aside, you should really be camel casing your variables in CakePHP. See the [Coding Standards](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html) in the documentation.

Comment: I actualy tried that way, so i was mess up syntax. 
Anyway thanks for help and advice!